# Ignore postname in permalink

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

I want to set my permalink as:

```
www.example.com/category/postid/postname
```

But I want WordPress to ignore the post name at the end, because I may change it later.

How can I do it with `.htaccess`, or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Being in `wp-admin/options-permalink.php` (Permalinks) you can easily set this using **Custom Structure**:

```
/%post_id%/%postname%/
```

[image: custom permalink structure]

So you can browse the **Hello World** post with:

```
http://example.com/1/hello-world/
```

But if you strip out the postname from the URL like below:

```
http://example.com/1/
```

You can still access the **Hello World** post.

> **CAUTION** Changing permalink in any live site may cause bad effect in SEO, and cause huge amount of 404 pages without proper redirection. So just think about it before switching to any changes in permalink.

Comment: What if I change the title? Will the old title work? Or it will be broken link ?

Comment: :) I changed my `/hello-world/` post permalink to `/somethjingas-dasd-sadsad/`, it's still taking me to the `#1` post that's previously "Hello World" :)